# Where is the alternate installation ISO for Ubuntu Saucy?

Tags: xorg, iso, alternate

I would like to download the alternate installation ISO for the current release, Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander, but I can't find it on the releases.ubuntu.com website. Aren't alternate ISOs provided anymore?

I need the alternate ISO because Xorg crashes on recent versions of Ubuntu when using old SIS on board graphics.

In fact, I just patched Ubuntu sources and generated a custom package for the xserver-xorg-video-sis driver on my PPA to try fix this problem, after installing with the minimal ISO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> As part of ongoing efforts to reduce the number of images we ship for Ubuntu, and to make the desktop image more useful in a variety of scenarios, Dmitrijs Ledkovs has been hard at work in quantal adding support for LVM, cryptsetup, and RAID to ubiquity.
>
> [...]
>
> It [dropping the alternate CDs] lets us tighten our focus on making the desktop CD shine: fewer images to QA, fewer different paths to get right (like the CD apt upgrader case) means more time to focus on the things that matter.

[More on the mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-August/035675.html).

That proposal got accepted so there is no alternate anymore. You need to use the normal installer.

> SIS on board graphics.

You need better hardware. SIS has not a lot of Linux affinity.

Comment: Easier said than done.

Comment: I know I know @LeonNardella :D

Answer (score 4):

The currently suggested way of installing Ubuntu on a graphically weak system is via the [netinstall/minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD). It still has a text based installer.