# Which installation images allow the installation of a command-line system?

Tags: command-line, system-installation, alternate

I would like to set up a minimal command-line system as a starting point for a custom desktop, as outlined in [Installation/LowMemorySystems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems) guide. What exact choice of the installation image do I have here?

I am going with the latest LTS, which, at time of this writing, is 14.04 LTS.

I am aware of two:

- 'netinst' [Minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) (`mini.iso`)
- [Lubuntu Alternate](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/PreviousReleases) (the [Alternate ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Alternate_ISO) page itself links to the latest non-LTS releases)

What makes me think of other options is the phrasing in the [Installation/LowMemorySystems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems) guide:

> To install a base system, boot from *any* **Alternate CD** and choose "Install a command-line system." It is *exactly the same* command-line system on *Lubuntu* Alternate CDs.

The words 'any' Alternate CD and 'exactly the same' ... 'on Lubuntu' suggest that there are other Alternate CD's, but I cannot find them.

Comment: There's another non-obvious choice of these installation images: for 14.04, you can choose either `mini.iso` *netinst* image from either [`trusty`](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/) or [`trusty-updates`](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/) directory. This would correspond to installing the 14.04.1 and 14.04.2 releases, respectively.

Comment: The important difference being: when installing from the 14.04.2 as opposed to installing the .0 or .1 and updating, one gets the newer 3.16 kernel and an updated version of the Xorg display server; when updating, we stay on 3.13 and older xorg unless we opt in. The corresponding installer for Lubuntu Alternate is the non-existent 14.04.2 (that's [another question](http://askubuntu.com/q/616438/181242)). I'll add this info with the links when I'll find them.

Answer (score 0):

> To install a base system, boot from any Alternate CD and choose "Install a command-line system." It is exactly the same command-line system on Lubuntu Alternate CDs.

I read it like this: "It is exactly the same command-line system *across all* Lubuntu alternate CDs".

(mind the plural in "CDs")

With "any Alternate CD" is referring to any of the [Lubuntu Alternate CDs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/PreviousReleases).

If there were multiple "other" Alternate CDs and only one Lubuntu Alternate CD it would have been: "To install a base system, boot from any Alternate CD and choose "Install a command-line system." It is exactly the same command-line system on Lubuntu Alternate CD".

(mind the singular in "CD")

Answer (score 0):

- Alternate CD images dropped with 12.10 releases, only for Lubuntu which are still built.

  **Reference:** [Where is the alternate installation ISO for Ubuntu Saucy?](https://askubuntu.com/a/371663/26246)
- Another option using Server images: when the `tasksel` pops up for services selection, Select none.

  It will install only the base command-line environment without any server services. May be SSH the only thing you need.

  [image]

  **Source:** [How do I install Ubuntu Server (step-by-step)](https://askubuntu.com/q/340965/26246)